# How do I make a site load PHP from another site if license key is correct?

Tags: php, licensing, loader

So, I have code on my server. I want someone else's website to load my HTML, CSS, and PHP code into their website but only if they have the correct license key in their PHP loader thing.

```php
# This is their code, the loader
include('https://example.com/index.php')
$license_key = 00000000;
```

```php
#This is MY code that's being loaded into their website
$valid_license_keys = ["10203", "000000"];
if ($license_key == $valid_license_keys) {
    echo Valid, loading page.;
} else {
echo "<h1>INVALID LICENSE!!!</h1>"
}
```

How can I actually make it work

Comment: You generally can't include PHP through a webserver. When someone accesses a `.php` file through your webserver, it will run the code on your server, not return the source code.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you want. There's nothing stopping them from downloading your code and removing the part that checks the license key.

Comment: However, Google "php license checking", you'll find some products that do this.

Comment: E.g. https://www.phpmillion.com/auto-php-licenser/ I can't vouch for how well it works.

Comment: @Barmar, so there is no way to load my code from my server to their website without them being able to see my code?

Comment: Of course not. For their server to be able to run the code, it has to see it.

Comment: You could obfuscate it to make it harder to understand, but it still has to be downloaded to their server.

Comment: This is why SaaS is popular -- the customers don't have to run the code on their servers.

Comment: I could not find anything besides phpmillion licenser. Anything else cheaper? @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

When you loading any file from 3rd site it will take some time and then your application will be very very slow.

Change your technical solution. 
For example `Ioncube Encoder` solution. PHP files are encoded and your code is safe.

Comment: Right. The usual idea is to use a solution that implements a licensing scheme of some kind. If licensing is implemented in PHP by checking a variable such as $_SERVER there is a chance to bypass that with a PHP prepend script that modifies the data to be what is expected, so the checking is best done in a C extension that checks licensing related data before any script runs. DIsclosure: I am associated with ionCube.